# ImageIcons not displayed - JAVA

Tags: java, swing, paint, drawimage, imageicon

My problem is that background image covers all ImageIcons I use in my JPanel. For example, in this code snippet, I'm trying to setIcon to one of the labels I have in my Panel. But the background image covers it. How can I fix this? It doesn't matter if I use label.setIcon() outside of paint method or inside of it.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);     
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);
            label1.setIcon(iconImage);

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The method to override is `paintComponent()`, not `paint()`. The icon should not be set in the `paintComponent()` method. And try drawing the image before calling `super.paintComponent()`, so that the "normal" painting is made over your background image. (not tested though, which is why I don't post this as an answer)

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the layout of your base panel to `BorderLayout`
2. Add a `JLabel` to the base pane, setting its icon to the background image
3. Set the layout if the `JLabel` to what ever you need
4. Add the remaining components to this label

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the label.seticon outside the overridden method.
Refer to:

> [How to set JFrame or JPanel Background Image in Eclipse Helios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816403/how-to-set-jframe-or-jpanel-background-image-in-eclipse-helios)

you can implement it as;

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
 g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
 }
```

OR

```
public void paint(Graphics g) { 
if (img!=null) g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null); 
super.paint(g); 
}
```

Comment: You are required to honour the paint chain. By not calling super.paint you are violating this contract. The paint methods do a lot of important work (such as painting the child components, double buffering (in the case of JComponents) and opacity), you should never avoid calling their super implementations - IMHO